# R - Function that selects specific character in a column in data frame and replaces it

Tags: r, function

I am trying to create a function in R that takes four arguments, namely:
data frame, number, character 1 and character 2.

What I am trying to have as an output is this:

```
test_df <- data.frame(col1 = c("matt", "baby"), col2 = c("john", "luck"))

my_function(test_df, 1, "u", "o")

col1 col2
mutt john
buby luck
```

I was just wondering how should I specifically define the function to take the [number] column the user is entering? For the renaming, I guess the function rename() would be fine. Do I need to substitue with [x,x]?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the language used ?

Comment: I don't get why your proposed function takes the arguments it does; it looks like you want to replace `a` with `u` (which can be accomplished just with `replace()`. Why the `1` and `"o"` arguments?

Comment: Oh my, I am so sorry, I have misread. Ok, so, the "number" argument should select the number coloumn (not character). I am very new to R, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to create a function that takes a column as an argument you need to split out the data frame and column specification (using `gsub()` to do the actual replacement):

```
my_function <- function(df, column, pattern, replacement) {

  gsub(pattern, replacement, df[[column]])

}
```

Which would work like:

```
my_function(df = test_df, column = 1, pattern = "a", replacement = "u")
## [1] "mutt" "buby"
```

But, this has the downside that if you want to loop over multiple columns, for example with `lapply()`, the list specification becomes more complicated:

```
test_df[] <- lapply(colnames(test_df), my_function, df = test_df, pattern = "a", replacement = "u")
test_df
#   col1 col2
# 1 mutt john
# 2 buby luck
```

Which is much more complicated than:

```
test_df   <- data.frame(test_df, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
test_df[] <- lapply(test_df, gsub, pattern = "a", replacement = "u")
test_df
#   col1 col2
# 1 mutt john
# 2 buby luck
```

(Note: ensure `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` for this to work. It's a good idea to use this as the default unless you explicitly want factors anyway)

Comment: But do you think there is a way to avoid the lapply? Or to avoid specifying the particular columns (in case you mean that by test_df [ ])?

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to avoid the use of `lapply()` if you want to loop over multiple columns? What are you trying to achieve in the end, and from what starting point?

Comment: I want to make it with one fucntion only, this is part of my exercise, namely, I should just call the function, put the data frame in it and generate the table with the changed column, without predfining the dataframe itself.

Comment: @Assen then the first part of my answer address that, but I would consider that bad practice

Comment: But I did not get what do you mean with test_df[], do I need to specify the columns there?

Comment: @Assen the square brackets `[]` just make sure that `lapply()` returns a data frame, rather than a list. You don't need to specify anything in it